# Read and print from a text file N lines at a time using a generator only

Tags: generator, python-3.6

Python 3.6.0

```
textfile = "f:\\mark\\python\\Alice_in_Wonderland.txt"

N = 60


def read_in_lines(file, n):
    with open(file) as fh:
        for i in range(n):
            nlines = fh.readline()
            if nlines:
                yield nlines
            else:
                break

for lines in read_in_lines(textfile, x):
    print(lines)
```

File is here:  https://www.gutenberg.org/files/11/11.txt

My goal is to read in this file N lines at a time, then print the lines,
then read in the next N lines, print, repeat...

If N = 3, output should look like:

```
line1
line2
line3

line4
line5
line6

line7
line8
line9

line10  <-- assumes this is the last line in the file
```

The above print pattern should hold for any value of 'N'.

If 'N' = 4:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4

line5
line6
line7
line8
```

etc.  You get the idea.

NO lists.  No built in functions (islice, etc.).

I need to use a generator only.
Each iteration *must* contain a string containing up to the
number of lines specified by 'N'.

Two issues:

1) The above code returns 'N' lines, then stops. I assume I need to put the whole
thing in a loop, but I am unsure of how to proceed. (Newbie...)

2) The file contains A LOT of blank lines. Every single time I try to use strip()
or any of it's variants, regardless of how big I make 'N' it only ever prints one line.

nlines = fh.readline().strip  <-- adding in .strip()
With N = 6000 I get:

```
Project Gutenberg's Alice's Adventures in Wonderland, by Lewis Carroll

Process finished with exit code 0
```

If I get rid of .strip() I get all the lines but not in the format I want.

I am on a Win 10 machine.  In Notepad++ all of the end of file symbols are CRLF.

Comment: I'm a lot closer.  I can print the first 'N' lines and then a space, but I can't seem to figure out how to proceed to the next 'N' lines, etc., until the end of the file.

Comment: textfile = "f:\\mark\\python\\Reuven_Lerner\\test.txt"
    
    x = 3
    
    
    def read_in_lines(file, n):
        with open(file) as fh:
            for i in range(n):
                nlines = fh.readline()
                if not nlines:
                    break
                yield nlines
        print("space")
    
    for lines in read_in_lines(textfile, x):
        print(lines.rstrip())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

```
textfile = "f:\\mark\\python\\test.txt"


def read_n(file, x):
    with open(file, mode='r') as fh:
        while True:
            data = ''.join(fh.readline() for _ in range(x))

            if not data:
                break

            yield data
            print()


for nlines in read_n(textfile, 5):
    print(nlines.rstrip())
```

Output:

```
abc
123
def
456
ghi

789
jkl
abc
123
def

456
ghi
789
jkl
abc

123
def
456
ghi
789

jkl
abc
123
def
456

ghi
789
jkl
```